# Visualizing grid map action arrow size

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I've got this nested list. Each nested list represents a cell in a 4 by 4 grid. Each element in the nested list represents the strength or value of an action. In the nested list, the first element represents UP, second represents RIGHT, 3rd DOWN, 4th LEFT.

How can I create visualized grid in python where each grid CELL has every arrow but varies in SIZE depending on the value?

```
[
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
  [-1.89, -2.6109, -2.61, -1.0], 
  [-2.46, -3.43, -2.47, -1.9], 
  [-3.40, -3.14, -2.71, -2.71], 
  [-1.0, -2.70, -2.70, -1.88], 
  [-1.89, -2.47, -3.0, -1.89], 
  [-2.70, -2.70, -2.70, -2.70], 
  [-3.43, -2.68, -1.9, -3.34], 
  [-1.9, -3.34, -2.46, -2.46], 
  [-2.70, -2.70, -2.70, -2.70], 
  [-3.33, -1.9, -1.9, -3.40], 
  [-2.61, -1.89, -1.0, -1.719], 
  [-2.70, -2.70, -3.40, -3.14], 
  [-3.08, -1.9, -2.46, -2.38], 
  [-2.67, -1.0, -1.89, -2.70], 
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
]
```

Comment: Hey! I am not that experienced in Matplotlib, but I wanted to give my view of this problem (that will probably help you solve this). You should start with creating a grid, of the required dimension (16x4, from the example). Then you iterate for each cell, add the required arrow, and scale it as per the value in the array. Like, for the first cell, you add a regular up arrow, and then scale it to 0. It may not be that efficient, but might do your work.

Comment: This sounds like a task, not a problem. Do you have problems finding how to plot arrows in matplotlib?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Im not even sure where to start looking to start this task.

Comment: To plot single arrows, [annotation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html), for your case also consider [quiver](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html)